# Raspbian fails to boot after fresh install

Tags: boot

So I have this problem.

I got a raspberry Pi 3 recently, and put NOOBS on a 16gb sd card. I stick the card into pi and the system installs as normal, boots into raspbian, i can connect to internet and do all that, basically it works.

But then when I turn off the pi either by just clicking shutdown or using command 'sudo shutdown' in terminal, it fails to boot second time. On the boot log there are two fail messages:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load/Save Random Seed
...
[FAILED] Failed to start Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes
```

As a result, raspbian doesn't boot into the desktop with apps etc, but just gives me a console prompt so I can still see files and directories, etc. but I can't use it as during a first boot. I have tried to reinstall raspbian a few times, I once managed to boot it on the second try, it showed the desktop etc, but instead of letters there were just rectangles (so i couldn't even type anything). I am so confused and annoyed, might that be issue of the sd card or the raspberry pi itself?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: What about the third time, does it boot normally then?

Answer (score 2):

When you boot and it goes into the command line, use the command

```
startx
```

This will start the GUI. Once this is done, check the

```
raspi-config
```

file settings and go on the boot_behavior option, set it to automatically boot into the GUI.

Hope this is of help.

Comment: It did the trick! Thanks a lot! Edit: in fact it did not. It goes past the log stage but then just a black screen with mouse pointer appears but it doesn't progress further:(

Comment: Try powering the Pi on whilst holding the shift key

Comment: Did you manage to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem, here is my solution for your reference.

1. Make sure that the OS works well in command line, the only problem is that the X Windows failed to load at boot up, or when initiated in command line by `sudo startx` or `sudo init 5`.
2. It's very likely that packages installed by `apt-get upgrade` conflict with X Windows. So check the apt upgrade log for suspicious packages. One quick way is using `grep -A 2 "2016-04-15" /var/log/apt/history.log`, where "2016-04-15" is when upgrade started.
3. The problem got solved after uninstalling the following three packages, the command is `sudo apt-get remove --purge <package-name>`.

   ```
   Start-Date: 2016-04-15  11:39:17
   Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
   Install: pypy:armhf (4.0.1+dfsg-1+rpi1), pypy-lib:armhf (4.0.1+dfsg-1+rpi1, automatic), pishutdown:armhf (0.1, automatic)
   --
   End-Date: 2016-04-15  11:42:41
   ```
4. Here is a [nice article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/debian-linux/ubuntu-linux-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade/) on apt upgrade and restore.