# Pi 4 won't boot after powered USB hub was connected

Tags: boot-issues, usb-hub

MY Pi 4 won't boot anymore after I connected a Sabrent HB-UMP3 powered USB Hub.  The Pi4 had been running just fine for around 2 years, yesterday I hotplugged the abovementioned hub and the Pi immediately stopped responding. I disconnected the hub and tried to reboot - to no avail. Not even the splashscreen and bootloader text are displayed, the TV connected via HDMI also does not detect any input. When connected to power, the Pi's red power LED lights up and the green LED next to it briefly lights up then turns off. Ethernet port LEDs light up when a cable is plugged in.  Apart from that, nothing happens, no response to ping.

Any ideas how to resurrect it ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspbian fails to boot after fresh install](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45746/raspbian-fails-to-boot-after-fresh-install)

Comment: Treat it as a boot failure and look through the many related questions.

Comment: That "duplicate" is substantially different from this question.

Comment: Welcome -- what happens when you plug it in with no SD card (particularly with the green ACT led).

Comment: @goldilocks "what happens when you plug it in with no SD card (particularly with the green ACT led)":  I used an external SDD to boot, so no SD card to start with.  The green ACT LED very briefty lights up then stays off.

Comment: @joan : thanks but it doesn't even get as far as reading the OS - no splash screen, in fact no output to HDMI at all.

Comment: @goldilocks Yes,but all these fail to boot problems can  be resolved by looking through the raspberrypi.org boot sticky.

Comment: @joan can you share a link to the 'raspberrypi.org boot sticky' ?  Couldn't find it....

Comment: never mind I found it....

Comment: So I went throught the boot sticky and performed the bootloader update with Pi Imager.  The HDMI display showed green and the green LED flashed, so indicated success. Then disconnected power and fired it up again - I managed to get the bootloader to come up once, then it turned off, and all other times again no HDMI output and the green LED doesn't come on.....guess it's a case for the graveyard ?

Answer (score 0):

Boot problems are frequently asked questions.

A comprehensive [boot problems sticky](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151) is available at the Raspberry Pi Foundation forums.

If the sticky  does not solve the problem the Pi is effectively dead.

Answer (score 0):

> I used an external SDD to boot ... The green ACT LED very briefty lights up then stays off

I've never booted with an external drive, so I don't know if there is a change in the behaviour of the ACT led, but normally with no SD card in it should light up and stay on.

If that was the previous behaviour (ie., it's not the same since the incident), this is probably further evidence pointing to the conclusion that the Pi is defunct.